# Why does acheter use indirect object pronouns?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

I don't understand why you would say "Je leur ai acheté" rather than "Je les ai acheté." Isn't that a direct object, the thing being bought?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two sentences have a different meanings.

> Je les ai achetés.

Indicates that you buy something (les), so it could be translated like "I've bought them"

> Je leur ai acheté.

Indicates that you buy something from somebody (leur), so it could be translated like "I've bought from them."

Comment: Sans oublier _Je les leur ai acheté_

Comment: _Je leur ai acheté_ peut vouloir aussi dire qu'on a acheté quelque chose pour quelqu'un (des enfants par exemple).

Comment: On ne fait pas l’accord ? *je les ai acheté**(e)s*** ?

Comment: Could this be interpreted to mean "I bought it for them"? Or only from them?

Comment: @temporary_user_name Could be both. *Acheter à quelqu'un* can mean *buy from someone* or *buy for someone*

Answer (score 2):

- J'ai acheté les chemises → je les ai achetées.
- J'ai acheté les livres → je les ai achetés.
- J'ai acheté quelque chose à quelqu'un → I bought something from somebody/ I bought something for somebody.
- Je (les) leur ai acheté → I bought (them) from them/I bought (them) for them.

**EDIT** (merci @Xoudo)
One must mention "Je les leur ai acheté" is quasi never used. "Je le lui ai acheté" is much more common.

Comment: One must mention *"Je les leur ai acheté" is quasi never used (never heard it). *"Je le lui ai acheté* is much more common.

Comment: @XouDo Thanks. I added your comment to my answer!